How sharp is the Triangle inequality for the Hamming distance
Given some binary space $\{-1,1\}^n$.
We can then define the Hamming distance as $d_h(a,b)=\sum_i |a_i-b_i| $.
My question now is how sharp the triangle inequality is more specifically I am wondering if:
\begin{equation}
d(a,b)+d(b,c)-d(a,c)\geq 2\frac{d(a,b)d(b,c)}{n}.
\end{equation}
So far I tried to do it explicitely but I am not even sure anymore whether I can assume this statement to be true or not. Any ideas would be very welcome.

Please don't redefine the concept of Hamming distance and continue calling it Hamming distance.

My excuses for the confusion

As in the comment, this is NOT Hamming distance but Hamming distance scaled by 2. The following triples, for example, violate your expected inequality since they achieve zero on the left hand side:
$$
n=3: a=(1,1,-1),b=(1,1,1),c=(1,-1,1)
$$
$$
n=4:a=(1,1,1,-1),b=(1,1,1,1),c=(-1,1,1,1)
$$

Thank you for your counter example.

And since for $n=3$, the first symbol is $1$ in all of $a,b,c,$  and thus provides no contributions to $d(\cdot,\cdot)$, there is even a counterexample when $n=2$.
